# Automatically adjust corresponding cells when using “=query”

Tags: google-sheets

I just learned how to use the `=query` function in Google Sheets, pulling information from one sheet to the next when a specific condition is met.

```
=query('Sheet1'!A:Z, "select B, D, E, F, G, I, L where A = 'WON'",0)
```

Example:

Sheet 1:

```
A AUG  WON
B SEPT PENDING
C SEPT LOST
D OCT  WON
```

Sheet 2:

```
A AUG
D OCT
```

In the second sheet, I add information in the columns after the ones `=query` pulled in, for example:

```
A AUG DANNY
D OCT NICKY
```

But when I change the source sheet, from PENDING to WON, it becomes this:

```
A AUG  DANNY
B SEPT NICKY
D OCT
```

How do I fix it so whatever information I put in the same row adjusts with the cells it was originally put with, leaving empty cells I can fill out beside the new entries?

Comment: Hi Isabel, why don't you share a doc with us. This way we can see directly what you are doing. The `QUERY` formula rocks, doesn't. Welcome on Web Applications !!

Comment: It's not clear. As was suggested previously please share a spreadsheet to see directly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

The values added to the right of QUERY() result aren't "tied" to the source range.

To "tie" them, add these values to the source sheet, as was suggested in a [comment posted by @pnuts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/69008/automatically-adjust-corresponding-cells-when-using-query#comment57268_69008).